# Не могу навести на выпадающее меню

Tags: html, css

Сделал вложенные ли-шки и при наведении почему-то не могу навести на подпункт. Какого-то еще расстояние есть между главным ли и вложенным:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

/* не бейте за лого в ли-шке*/

```css
.main-nav {
    float: left;
}
.main-nav ul {
    display: block;
}
.main-li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 28px;
    margin-left: 18px;   
}
.main-li::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    background: #bccdc4;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 12px; 
    left: 12px;      
}
.main-li:hover::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";  
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 12px; 
    left: 12px;    
}
.main-li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}
.main-li a:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #333333;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.main-nav .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 37px;
    display: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 143px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f8f7f4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.submenu > li {
    display: block;
}
.submenu > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.submenu > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.main-li:hover > .submenu {
    display: block;
}
.main-li:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.main-li:first-child::before {
    content: "";
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header container clearfix">
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="main-li">
        <img src="img/Logo.png" alt="logo">
      </li>
      <li class="main-li">
        <a href="">Каталог</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-li"><a href="">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
      <li class="main-li"><a href="">О компании</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="main-nav-right">
    <a href="">
      <div class="search"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="open">Вход</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="basket">Пусто</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Закрывающего тега у `img` не существует.
2. Вы сделали так, что пока вы наводите на меню, показывается подменю. Следовательно когда не наводите - оно не показывается. Так как между меню и подменю расстояние, пока ведете, это условие не срабатывает. Добавьте прозрачную подложку на подменю, чтобы можно было довести мышь до цели:

```css
.main-nav {
  float: left;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: block;
}

.main-li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 28px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.main-li::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  background: #bccdc4;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 12px;
  left: 12px;
}

.main-li:hover::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 12px;
  left: 12px;
}

.main-li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.main-li a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #333333;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.main-nav .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 37px;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 143px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  padding: 0;
  /*overflow: hidden; убрать*/
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f8f7f4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.submenu>li {
  display: block;
}

.submenu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main-li:hover>.submenu {
  display: block;
}

.main-li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.main-li:first-child::before {
  content: "";
  display: none;
}

/*new*/
.submenu:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:-38px;
  height:38px;
  
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header container clearfix">
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="main-li"><img src="img/Logo.png" alt="logo" />
        <!--<!--</img> - такого закрывающего тега не существует-->
      </li>
      <li class="main-li"><a href="">Каталог</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-li"><a href="">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
      <li class="main-li"><a href="">О компании</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="main-nav-right">
    <a href="">
      <div class="search"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="open">Вход</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="basket">Пусто</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Не думал что так можно, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.main-nav {
    float: left;
}
.main-nav ul {
    display: block;
}
.main-li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 28px;
    margin-left: 18px;   
}
.main-li::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    background: #bccdc4;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 12px; 
    left: 12px;      
}
.main-li:hover::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";  
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 12px; 
    left: 12px;    
}
.main-li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}
.main-li a:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #333333;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.main-nav .submenu-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 143px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    padding: 0;
    
    padding: 37px 0 0;    
}

.main-nav .submenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f8f7f4;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.submenu > li {
    display: block;
}
.submenu > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.submenu > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.main-li:hover > .submenu-wrap {
    display: block;
}
.main-li:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.main-li:first-child::before {
    content: "";
    display: none;
}


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header container clearfix">
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="main-li">
        <img src="img/Logo.png" alt="logo">
      </li>
      <li class="main-li">
        <a href="">Каталог</a>
        <div class="submenu-wrap">
          <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="main-li"><a href="">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
      <li class="main-li"><a href="">О компании</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="main-nav-right">
    <a href="">
      <div class="search"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="open">Вход</div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="basket">Пусто</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Не наводится, потому что пустое пространство в несколько пикселей до `submenu`, решить можно сокращением расстояния, либо оберткой с верхним отступом в несколько пикселей.